# Post doesn't show up in dashboard - wordpress, MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-error-1062

I recently redesigned my site, complete with a new database, but I wanted to grab all of the posts from my old wp site to have in the new one.  There were only three.  I imported all of the rows in the database that pertained to said posts to my new database.  Only two of the posts showed up.

When I tried to manually import the third post, I get this:

```
SQL query:

-- -- Database: `erisdesi_wp` -- -- -- Dumping data for table `wp_posts` -- INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES (188, 1, '2010-08-26 04:42:37', '2010-08-26 04:42:37', 'Hold yr horses! We’re building it!\r\n
\r\n\r\n
', 'Design Blog', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', '110-revision-6', '', '', '2010-08-26 04:42:37', '2010-08-26 04:42:37', '', 110, 'http://www.erisdesigns.net/http:/www.erisdesigns.net/wordpress/', 0, 'revision', '', 0), (2, 1, '2010-07-17 18:28:39', '2010-07-17 18:28:39', 'Documentation #1062 - Duplicate entry
```

I'm pretty new to MySQL...any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance for furthering my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the import and export tools WordPress has (under the tools menu in your wp-admin). It sounds like you are trying to import two rows with the same ID. That might happen if you tried to import the same posts twice, or import into an existing table that already has a post in it with the same ID.

Comment: I actually got the rows to successfully import, but the post is still not available in my dashboard.

Comment: After a night of frustration, I came to find out that I was missing an important entry.  Imported and fixed.  Giving you the check, @Dan Grossman, thanks for your response.